# Add page break after match of certain class on div with mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am converting a report (in html)to pdf using mPDF library, but is putting all pages into one. I want to add a page  break after a certain  but I haven't been successful.

**html**

```
 <div class='text my_form' style='margin:0px 0 0 0; padding:0px 0 0 0;  border-style:dotted; border-color:white;'>
```

I'm passing this to the php as $html

**PHP**

```
 require_once ("./libraries/MPDF57/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf=new mPDF("", "Letter", "", "", 10, 10);
```

I want to add a page break after it finds the div shown above

```
 preg_match_all("/((\<div\s)(class='text\smy_form'[\s\w\s]*border-color:white)(.+?)(\>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach($matches as $value) {
       $html= $mpdf->AddPage();
     }

     $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

     $filename = "documentx.pdf";

    $mpdf->Output($fileName, 'F');
```

However, is not working, please help me go through the right track :)

Answer (score 29):

I use this code before closing the foreach tag: `$html .= "&lt;pagebreak /&gt;";`

```
foreach($matches as $value) {
   $html .= "<pagebreak />";
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

I've been successful without using AddPage and instead using css to add the page break, with `page-break-after:always` and for the last div, `page-break-after:avoid`.  Maybe something like this would work:

```
$len = count($matches);
$i = 1;
foreach($matches as $value) {
    if ($i < $len) {
        $html .= "<div style='page-break-after:always'>" . $html . "</div>";
    } else {
        $html .= "<div style='page-break-after:avoid'>" . $html . "</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: When I using this my $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer); is not printing ...

Answer (score 0):

```
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $mpdf->use_kwt = true;
        $html = $this->load->view('client_tid_pdf', $data,true);
        $mpdf->autoPageBreak = true;
        $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin='stretch';
        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output(); // opens in browser
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).